# replacing a part of a string using rexeg excluding a specific strings using notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

got some problems replacing multiple variable names in multiple files and have no idea how i can solve this

**current format**

```
//"Pain" should be changed to "Items"
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Pain_MorphinePainCureValueP", 1.0);
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Pain_MorphinePainMinForFullCureP", 0.5);
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Pain_MorphineKillPointP", 1);
//"MedicalActions"  should be changed to "Items"
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_MedicalActions_Morphine_DamageHealing", 0.5);

//"Feature" should remain
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Feature_EnableMorphine", true);
```

**cargeted format**

```
//"Pain" should be changed to "Items"
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Items_MorphinePainCureValueP", 1.0);
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Items_MorphinePainMinForFullCureP", 0.5);
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Items_MorphineKillPointP", 1);
//"MedicalActions"  should be changed to "Items"
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Items_Morphine_DamageHealing", 0.5);

//"Feature" should remain
assignValue("X39_MS2_var_Feature_EnableMorphine", true);
```

**what i got so far**

```
//is not working but more or less the latest stage of progress
(X39_MS2_..._)^(?!Feature.*)(?=[a-zA-Z]*)(_.*Morphine.*)

//is working but does not ignores the Feature tag ...
(X39_MS2_..._)([a-zA-Z]*)(_.*Morphine.*)

//Was the base of testing which is working with the above examples but is lacking the brackets around the X39_MS2_ tag + the rest of the string)
^(?!.*Feature.*).*_
```

if im lacking something in this please tell
will try to provide everything you guys need as i now try since about ~1h to solve this but got no further progress : /

kindly regards
X39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this in N++:

Search: `(?<=_)(?:Pain|MedicalActions)(?=_)`

Replace: `Items`

The key is that the words you are looking for are preceded by a loobehind and a lookahead, each looking for `_`

Comment: ahhhh

thx ^^ (regex is somehow a hell of a bitch ... final result of the working regex string is now 
   
     "(?<=X39_MS2_..._)(?:Pain|MedicalActions)(?=.*Morphine.*)")

Basically (?<=...) is the beginning and (?=...) is the end
and (?:...|...|...) are the search arguments?
(just for better understanding ^^ worked very well)

Comment: just discovered some strange problem Oo
Searching the string works fine but replacing is just acting like im searching the next entry instead of replacing it : /

Comment: @x39 Works on my side. Maybe open a new question to describe the problem? Could be a settings thing. Screenshots of your search window may be useful (but if so the best site is superuser).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change pain Pain or MedicalActions to Items just use a regex replace for:

```
Pain|MedicalActions
```

to

```
Items
```

or do you only want those that have that prefix? if so then just do

```
X39_MS2_var_(Pain|MedicalActions)
```

and replace with:

```
X39_MS2_var_Items
```

EDIT:
if you want to use your regex there then just do something like:

```
(X39_MS2_..._)([a-zA-Z]*)(_Morphine.*)
```

as this ensures that morphine is the next thing. It'd be much simpler to just change the individual parts though...

Comment: its more like so:
(PREFIX) SOMETHING (SOMETEXT "Morphine" SOMETEXT)
needs to be replaced with 
(PREFIX) Items (SOMETEXT "Morphine" SOMETEXT)